# more than one dropdown menu in the navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

This is my first question on sof.

I want to use à navbar with bootstrap.
This navbar has to contain two dropdown menu in the right part of the navbar
The two drop down have to be in the same shape even i display the page in a mobile screen on desktop screen.

They have to behave the same way in both screens.

Always a dropdown menu and never collapse.

The first dropdownmenu is a language selector
The second dropdownmenu is a classic menu

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a design question that may require a lot of custom code to meet the design requirements.

I think you should start by searching the WWW: bootstrap navbar no collapse and you will find some ideas.

Finally, learn how to use the Advanced Search features for stackoverflow as they are very useful. A stackoverflow search query like this for example...

[bootstrap] "navbar" "collapse"

Mark my comments as an answer if you agree

Comment: Thanks a lot but i found out a way to display both dropdown menus